# Docusaurus2: Recommended way to import localized MDX in React?

Tags: docusaurus

Is there a known best way to support i18n for markdown imported into React? The documentation for the translation stuff indicates that it's in flux in Docusaurus 2; this case doesn't seem to be answered.  I've found a cumbersome way of importing different markdown pages into React based on language, but I'd like to do it more efficiently.

Here's how I can do it.  This requires an import statement for
each language version I want to support and then a lookup of the appropriate language version.  It seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

```
import MDXHome from 'docs/home.mdx'
import FRHome from 'docs/fr/home.mdx'

const MDXImports = {
  home: {
    '/': (<MDXHome />),
    '/fr/': (<FRHome />)
  },
}

function Home() {
  const context = useDocusaurusContext();
  const {siteConfig = {}} = context;

  return (
<!-- // Layout stuff here -->
      {MDXImports.home[${siteConfig.baseUrl}]}
<!--// More stuff -->
  );
}
```